# Eclipse project folder shows error But not showing error in any files inside folder

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

My eclipse project folder is showing error but no error is shown anywhere inside, am not able to run my project in tomcat due to this error.

Note: It seems, after I took latest update from SVN this error occured

Any Idea why this happened

Comment: Did you `refresh`/`reload`/`build` your workspace/project ?

Comment: Configure your buildPath **RighClick on Project > BuildPath > Configure BuildPath**

Comment: Look in the "Problems" view. Maybe you have a problem in your buildpath.

Comment: tried restart, refresh, build my workspace/project .. No luck

Comment: @Jens thanks for bringing up the "Problems" view. It lead me right to the problem. Turned out I had a cmd line that had the a folder in the bin folder open, and so eclipse couldnt delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Detailed explanation here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Add the required jar files to your path

**OR**

May be the added jar files path mismatched.

Configure project buildPath by

**`RighClick on Project > BuildPath > Configure BuildPath`**

Answer (score 5):

Right click on maven project in eclipse > Maven > Update project.

It solved my problem.

If the problem still persists, look in the Problems tab (Window Menu > show view  > Problems) and it should give the description of the error.

Answer (score 1):

1. RighClick on Project > BuildPath > Configure BuildPath  - check for missing library.
2. menu > project > clear
3. restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Project-->Build Path --> Configure Build Path-->Java Build Path-->Libraries--> Maven Dependencies-->Here you can view error Dependencies..
Delete and add appropriate Jars